# Issue with de-serialization from json to object containing enums

Tags: java, enums, jackson, swagger

Having issue with enum de-serialization using jackson2.9.8. Same works fine with Gson.
Model is Auto generated from swagger api definition

using Gson, it works fine. With jackson it doesn't work for 011, 013 and 019 but work for other values

snippet of Swagger api definition

serviceCode:
          type: string
          enum:
            - "001"
            - "002"
            - "003"
            - "004"
            - "005"
            - "007"
            - "008"
            - "009"
            - "011"
            - "013"
            - "019"

Auto generated code ( removed the getter/setter for readability)

```
public class ProcessErrorTest1 {
    static String errorJson =
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"timestamp\": \"2019-07-29 11:55:48\",\n" +
            "      \"serviceCode\": \"019\",\n" +
            "      \"message\": \"service failed. \",\n" +
            "      \"rootException\": {\n" +
            "        \"source\": \"test\",\n" +
            "        \"reasonCode\": \"2131\",\n" +
            "        \"reasonText\": \"test\"\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "}";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        AppErrorResponse error = mapper.readValue(errorJson, AppErrorResponse.class);
       // Gson gson = new Gson();
        //AppErrorResponse error = gson.fromJson(errorJson, AppErrorResponse.class);
        System.out.println("error::" + error);
    }
}

public class AppErrorResponse {

  @SerializedName("message")
  private String message = null;

  @SerializedName("rootException")
  private ErrorResponse rootException = null;
  /**
   * Gets or Sets serviceCode
   */
  @JsonAdapter(ServiceCodeEnum.Adapter.class)
  public enum ServiceCodeEnum {
    _001("001"),
    _002("002"),
    _003("003"),
     _004("004"),
    _005("005"),
    _007("007"),
    _008("008"),
    _009("009"),
    _011("011"),
    _013("013"),
   // @JsonProperty("019") if add this , it works fine. But can't modify the auto generated code as it is available as jar
    _019("019");
  }
  @SerializedName("serviceCode")
  private ServiceCodeEnum serviceCode = null;

  @SerializedName("timestamp")
  private String timestamp = null;

}

public class ErrorResponse {

  @SerializedName("reasonCode")
  private String reasonCode = null;

  @SerializedName("reasonText")
  private String reasonText = null;

  @SerializedName("source")
  private String source = null;
}
```

jersey1:jackson generated code

```
import java.util.Objects;
import com.bt.consumer.appointment.dto.MAC2ErrorResponse;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;
public class AppErrorResponse {
  @JsonProperty("message")
  private String message = null;

  @JsonProperty("rootException")
  private ErrorResponse rootException = null;

  public enum ServiceCodeEnum {
    _001("001"),
    _002("002"),
    _003("003"),
    _004("004"),
    _005("005"),
    _007("007"),
    _008("008"),
    _009("009"),
    _011("011"),
    _013("013"),
    _019("019");

    private String value;

    ServiceCodeEnum(String value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
    @JsonValue
    public String getValue() {
      return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return String.valueOf(value);
    }
    @JsonCreator
    public static ServiceCodeEnum fromValue(String text) {
      for (ServiceCodeEnum b : ServiceCodeEnum.values()) {
        if (String.valueOf(b.value).equals(text)) {
          return b;
        }
      }
      return null;
    }

  }
  @JsonProperty("serviceCode")
  private ServiceCodeEnum serviceCode = null;

  @JsonProperty("timestamp")
  private String timestamp = null;
}

import java.util.Objects;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;
public class ErrorResponse {
  @JsonProperty("reasonCode")
  private String reasonCode = null;

  @JsonProperty("reasonText")
  private String reasonText = null;

  @JsonProperty("source")
  private String source = null;
}
```

It works fine for all apart from _011, _013 and _019 using jackson
Error meessage:-
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `ServiceCodeEnum` from String "011": value not one of declared Enum instance names: [_011, _001, _002, _003, _004, _005, _007, _008, _009, _013, _019]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your annotations are targeting Gson and not Jackson, you should generate your pojos for Jackson instead of Gson. The line `@JsonAdapter(ServiceCodeEnum.Adapter.class)` is an adapter which handles the conversion of that enum for Gson.

---

Looking at swagger codegen documentation you'll find the section on generation https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#customizing-the-generator

There it is said: `For all the unspecified options default values will be used.`

With the following table listed above:

```
CONFIG OPTIONS
    modelPackage
        package for generated models

    apiPackage
        package for generated api classes
...... (results omitted)
    library
        library template (sub-template) to use:
        jersey1 - HTTP client: Jersey client 1.18. JSON processing: Jackson 2.4.2
        jersey2 - HTTP client: Jersey client 2.6
        feign - HTTP client: Netflix Feign 8.1.1.  JSON processing: Jackson 2.6.3
        okhttp-gson (default) - HTTP client: OkHttp 2.4.0. JSON processing: Gson 2.3.1
        retrofit - HTTP client: OkHttp 2.4.0. JSON processing: Gson 2.3.1 (Retrofit 1.9.0)
        retrofit2 - HTTP client: OkHttp 2.5.0. JSON processing: Gson 2.4 (Retrofit 2.0.0-beta2)
        google-api-client - HTTP client: google-api-client 1.23.0. JSON processing: Jackson 2.8.9
        rest-assured - HTTP client: rest-assured : 3.1.0. JSON processing: Gson 2.6.1. Only for Java8
```

This line is probably whats being used:

`okhttp-gson (default) - HTTP client: OkHttp 2.4.0. JSON processing: Gson 2.3.1`

You need to specify a library which uses Jackson and a HTTP client which you want.

Comment: @Nandeesh `jersey2` doesnt seem to specify Jackson. Can you try `jersey1` or `google-api-client`

Comment: jersey2 does used jackson. I can see the import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator; in the auto generated classes. I will try with jersey1

Comment: with jersey1 as well it's same issue. `ServiceCodeEnum from String value '019': value not one of declared Enum instance names: [001, 002, 003, 004, 005, 007, 008, 009, 011, 013, 019]`

Comment: @Nandeesh Could you update your question with the generated DTOs using Jersey?

Comment: @ug I have updated with generated DTO using jersey1. If I use the serviceCode as 010 which is not part of enum, still i get the successful response, but gives back the service code as 019 `class AppErrorResponse {
    message: service failed. 
    rootException: class ErrorResponse {
        reasonCode: 2131
        reasonText: test
        source: test
    }
    serviceCode: 019
    timestamp: 2019-07-29 11:55:48
}`

Comment: @ug  it works fine. It looks like I didn't tested properly. Apologies.

Comment: @Nandeesh np! Thanks for following up so I wasnt left wondering :)